# How do I copy-paste a massive excel file from a virtual machine server to my local machine?

Tags: sql, excel, csv, citrix

I am running a large query that returns about 150,000 rows. I access the database remotely via Citrix XenApp and, when I run a query I am having trouble copy-pasting the output into my local Excel spreadsheet. Each time I try copy-pasting the whole data (which is about 150,000 rows) , I get "Excel cannot paste the data"

But what is strange is that, when I run a query that returns just a *single* row, I can copy paste it fine.

The data is split into 3 sheets (sheet1, sheet4, sheet5). And the sheets have 65,000 ; 65000; and 19000 rows each.

Is there a way to copy only 5,000 rows at a time quickly? (i.e without dragging and selecting manually 5,000 rows each time ) ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you save the sheet / sheets as CSV then copy and paste using notepad ?